# Coffeescript in angularjs generator cannot find js file in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I test the `generator-angular` and made a test app like this

```
yo angular
```

then I have read in the documentation that I can use coffeescript instead of js files, so I created a controller in coffeescript named `user` like this

```
yo angular:contrller user --coffee
```

I change the controller in app.js file to `UserCtrl` then I run it using

```
grunt serve
```

As I check the console, because it ain't working, it says

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://127.0.0.1:9000/scripts/controllers/user.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed the same commands and it was working fine. 
When you run the

> yo angular:contrller user --coffee

it should create two files

```
  create app/scripts/controllers/user.js
  create test/spec/controllers/user.js
```

And also without changing the app.js first check and see whether you can run the

> grunt server

What I would suggest is that re run the

> yo angular

Command and make sure all the files are installed properly as it takes couple of min to install all the dependencies based on your selection.

Comment: I will create .coffee files not .js

Comment: Yes, those .cofee files convert to .js finally. Anyway I do not get any errors. So better to clear the folder and rerun the above steps. Also when you run "grunt" command do you get any errors?